# svg images not displayed on Windows platform

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to set some svg images on ImageButton controls in a Maui project. I noticed that they are displayed correctly on Android and iOS platforms but on Windows they doesn't appears.
The images resides on Resources > Images.

Here is a simple Xaml snippet that I use:

```
            <ImageButton
                Style="{StaticResource ImageBtnTitleStyle}"
                Source="worker"
                IsVisible="{Binding Avviato}"
                Command="{Binding ApriCommand}"/>
```

In this example, "worker" is a svg image, named "worker.svg".

What can I do to display them on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET MAUI converts SVG files to PNG files. Therefore, when adding an SVG file to your .NET MAUI app project, it should be referenced from XAML or C# with a .png extension. You need to change your code as follows:

```
<ImageButton
             Style="{StaticResource ImageBtnTitleStyle}"
             Source="worker.png"
             IsVisible="{Binding Avviato}"
             Command="{Binding ApriCommand}"/>
```